# Why is my task in "WaitingForActivation" status after calling SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Given the following code:

```
           Dim t As Date = Now
            Dim e As New AsynchronousExecutionEventArgs
            AsyncDataExecuting = False
            Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(Cmd, SqlClient.SqlCommand).BeginExecuteNonQuery()

            Do While Not (result.IsCompleted Or result.CompletedSynchronously)
                AsyncDataExecuting = True
                RaiseEvent OnAsynchronousProcessing(Me, e)

                If CInt(DateLib.TimeSpan(t, DateLib.TimeSpanTypeEnum.TicksPerMillisecond)) > AsynchronousProcessingDelay Then
                    _Common.InvokeDoEvents() 'we do this getting the datareader asynchronously so'
                End If
                If e.mCancel Then
                    If Not Cmd Is Nothing Then Cmd.Cancel()
                    If Not Cmd Is Nothing Then Cmd.Dispose()
                    AsyncDataExecuting = False
                    Exit Function
                End If
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(AsynchronousProcessingSleep)
            Loop
            If Not Cmd Is Nothing Then
                ExecSql = ToStr(CType(Cmd, SqlClient.SqlCommand).EndExecuteNonQuery(result))
            End If
```

I am perplexed why sometimes the result object is:

```
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation {1}, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Object)
```

I would have thought that BeginExecuteNonQuery would not allow a task to be in "WaitingForActivation" mode. How do I either (1) prevent the task from being in WaitingForActiviation mode or (2) Activate it?

PS: The strange part is that if I setup a SQL Profiler I see the SQL executing and the statement is executed successfully but the code is stuck in a loop since the "IsCompleted" flag never gets sent.

Comment: Is it possible that another thread is using (or trying to use) the same SqlCommand object?

Comment: This interweaving of async DB calls and UI access mixed with a dose of cancellation, polling and race conditions is really nasty stuff. Rethink this. For example move the DB access to a background Task/Thread.

Comment: @usr - I agree with you. This is legacy code I am planning to rewrite using async once we upgrade to .NET 4.5. For now, am just trying to maintain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WaitingForActiviation` means that this task is based on `TaskCompletionSource` and has not been completed by the owner. I don't understand how this name came to be.

So this is normal. It means the task is not completed. I doubt the SQL query is really done and `Task.IsCompleted` is really false. If you think this is the case post more details so that the mistake can be found.

Why are you using the old APM pattern (`IAsyncResult`)? This is obsolete. Use `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Comment: We're still on .NET 3.5, hence the old construct

Comment: That's the interesting part - there isn't much more to it. Maybe somewhere in the grand scheme of things there could be a race condition that is forming but am going to keep looking.

Comment: If this was really 3.5 you should not see Task-related stuff. Those types were added in 4.0.

Comment: so this is another interesting point. The library/DLL where this code resides is compiled using .NET 3.5. The application which is importing this DLL is compiled using .NET 4.5.1. Why this .NET 3.5 DLL is using a .NET 4.x object is also interesting. Maybe something is going on because of that?

Comment: Both libs are referencing ADO.NET. Only the latest version is loaded (which is 4.5.1). The old lib is redirected to use the new ADO.NET version.

Comment: So is there actually a problem you are having? This task state is normal.

Comment: well, yes, how do I make this task run? and why doesn't it run by default when it is created by BeginExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: It runs. Are you sure it never completes? How exactly did you find out? Call result.WaitHandle.Wait() and measure how long it takes. It should complete.